# Error installing scrapy in python 3.5

Tags: python, scrapy

I am installing Scrapy in Python 3.5. I am referring to the installation guide [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html) .

I have installed `pip` and `conda`. I tried both ways mentioned in the guide, but am getting this error:

[image: error installing scrapy]

I have already installed `pip` and `minoconda`:

```
conda install -c scrapinghub scrapy
```

and

```
 pip install Scrapy
```

What is wrong with the installation?

Comment: Has pip worked for you on other installations?

Comment: You should run those commands in your terminal, not in the python interpreter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to install `scrapy` in the python interpreter, you should install the package in your terminal. What's more, one requirement of installing `scrapy` is python 2.7, you're using python 3.5

---

Update:

Good news: [Python 3 is Coming to Scrapy](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/02/04/python-3-support-with-scrapy-1-1rc1/), you can try `pip install scrapy==1.1.0rc1` now. Note that there are still some limitations, but won't be long that `scrapy` will have full of 3.x support. Pay close attention to the `scrapy` development ;)

Comment: i am getting same error in terminal also.

Comment: @KrunalParmar Could you paste the full error log?

Comment: @KrunalParmar Ah, because scapy don't support Python 3.x now，you can see it in the link you provide.

Comment: copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: Until Twisted supports Python 3.5 which it does not it will not work on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy doesn't work with Python 3. At the moment, scrapy works only with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

You can pip install scrapy on python 3.5+, you just have to pip install all the deppendencies first - from here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

- pip install lxml
- pip install parsel
- pip install w3lib
- pip install twisted
- pip install cryptography
- pip install cryptography
- pip install pyOpenSSL

and finally

- pip install scrapy - worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Before installing Scrapy on Python 3.5 on Windows 10 in virtualenv
Install lxml,PyDispatcher then simpy install Scrapy code is attached.

```
    (pymote_env) C:\Users\DDSHARMA\Documents\pymote_env>pip install PyDispatcher
Collecting PyDispatcher
Installing collected packages: PyDispatcher
Successfully installed PyDispatcher-2.0.5

(pymote_env) C:\Users\DDSHARMA\Documents\pymote_env>pip install Scrapy
Collecting Scrapy
  Using cached Scrapy-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in c:\users\ddsharma\documents\pymote_env\lib\site-packages (from Scrapy)
Collecting service-identity (from Scrapy)
  Using cached service_identity-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Twisted>=10.0.0 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached Twisted-16.4.1.tar.bz2
Collecting parsel>=0.9.3 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached parsel-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from Scrapy)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-16.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in c:\users\ddsharma\documents\pymote_env\lib\site-packages (from Scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in c:\users\ddsharma\documents\pymote_env\lib\site-packages (from Scrapy)
Collecting queuelib (from Scrapy)
  Using cached queuelib-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting w3lib>=1.15.0 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached w3lib-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cssselect>=0.9 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached cssselect-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1-modules (from service-identity->Scrapy)
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1 (from service-identity->Scrapy)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs (from service-identity->Scrapy)
  Using cached attrs-16.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zope.interface>=4.0.2 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->Scrapy)
  Using cached zope.interface-4.3.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Collecting cryptography>=1.3.4 (from pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached cryptography-1.5.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\users\ddsharma\documents\pymote_env\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.0.2->Twisted>=10.0.0->Scrapy)
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached idna-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Using cached cffi-1.8.3-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=1.3.4->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Downloading pycparser-2.16.tar.gz (230kB)
    100% |################################| 235kB 286kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: Twisted, pycparser
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Twisted ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\0e\53\62\e7b4cea7df9113fb2818b224eb5d143be981568d9c43057a0a
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycparser ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\DDSHARMA\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\34\cc\b5\34e805b130a9227f0681d5517cf554d950bb0361c3a373496f
Successfully built Twisted pycparser
Installing collected packages: pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, idna, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, attrs, service-identity, zope.interface, Twisted, w3lib, cssselect, parsel, queuelib, Scrapy
Successfully installed Scrapy-1.2.1 Twisted-16.4.1 attrs-16.2.0 cffi-1.8.3 cryptography-1.5.2 cssselect-1.0.0 idna-2.1 parsel-1.0.3 pyOpenSSL-16.2.0 pyasn1-0.1.9 pyasn1-modules-0.0.8 pycparser-2.16 queuelib-1.4.2 service-identity-16.0.0 w3lib-1.15.0 zope.interface-4.3.2

(pymote_env) C:\Users\DDSHARMA\Documents\pymote_env>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install scrapy on Python 3.5.

1. Check to see if you are able to install these Twisted, lxml and pyOpenSSL.
2. In my case I got error in installing lxml. I fixed it by downloading `lxml‑3.6.4‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml based on your Python and windows version. (Credit to Christoph Gohlke's generosity for sharing this library.). Installed it using the following command:

---

```
pip install lxml‑3.6.4‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
```