# Using scrapy for python 3.5 on Windows AND using pip for python 2.7 after installed and used pip for python 3.5

Tags: python, scrapy, pip, version

FIRST QUESTION:
I was using python 2.7, but I started learning web scraping and the tutorial I read use python 3.5. So I installed python 3.5 and pip for that. After I installed scrapy I cannot run my project using

```
scrapy crawl mywork
```

it reports an error like this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_win32stdio'
```

And then I read that python 3.5 with scrapy is now not supported on windows, but Ubuntu. So I want to ask if there is any configuration that I didn't know?

---

SECOND QUESTION:
And in order to avoid the problem I want to go back to python 2.7 and installing scrapy for 2.7.
It is not hard to differentiate pip for 2.x and 3.x version by

```
py -2 -m pip isntall thePackage
```

But the PROBLEM is that after I installed python 3.5 and pip for 3.5,
I cannot use pip for py2.7 anymore. It seems that I cannot link to the url for python 2.7 or something like that.

Whatever package I am installing in 2.7, it goes like

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/.../: There was a problem 

confirming the ssl certificate: [Erron 185090050] _ssl.c:344 ...
....
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
....
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5-py2.7.egg
```

I do love python but the installing pakcages part is really annoying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run multiple python version on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583367/how-to-run-multiple-python-version-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks, I've read this one before but I dont think it resolves my question, i'm asking why pip not working when switching back to python2.7, and how to use scrapy in python3.5 in windows.

Comment: have you checked your environment variables?

Comment: the pip for my old version of python 2.7.8 works fine until I installed python3.4.  I think that python3,4 might change some configuration in python2. Anyway, I uninstalled python2.7.8 and installed python2.7.11 because I read that pip is automatically installed since 2.7.11 version.

Comment: Then, I started to install twisted which is a package required for scrapy. And I got the "valueError: [u'path']". I then checked if the same problem happens in both py2 and py3 when installing different packages. And I found that the Error only happens when I installing c-required packages in py2. I read a question in stackoverflow saying that I should install pywin32 or vs2008(with x64 Compiler and Tools, for the x64 system). But I've already have pywin32 in py2 and it doesn't help. And I just happened to have a vs2010 in my laptop, so I installed it and restarted my computer.

Comment: And then, I can install twisted smoothly. After that, I tried to run scrapy in cmd and it raised a new error asking for pyasn1.  To make sure that there was no problem with the scrapy itself I used pip to upgrade scrapy in py2 and after doing that everything works fine. And from the log it seems that pyasn1 is also a dependency for scrapy.ersion.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your issue using pip, you need to check and modify your environment variables:

https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html

> 3.3.1. Excursus: Setting environment variables Windows has a built-in dialog for changing environment variables (following guide applies to
>   XP classical view): Right-click the icon for your machine (usually
>   located on your Desktop and called “My Computer”) and choose
>   Properties there. Then, open the Advanced tab and click the
>   Environment Variables button.
>
> In short, your path is:
>
> My Computer ‣ Properties ‣ Advanced ‣ Environment Variables In this
>   dialog, you can add or modify User and System variables. To change
>   System variables, you need non-restricted access to your machine (i.e.
>   Administrator rights).

Otherwise, remove pip and reinstall, as it might be related to the pip version you have ([pip connection failure: cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294997/pip-connection-failure-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http-pypi-python-org-simpl))

as per why scrapy is not woking using python 3.5 - this questionn has already been answered here: [Error installing scrapy in python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125752/error-installing-scrapy-in-python-3-5/35126140)

and from a comment in this post:

> Until Twisted supports Python 3.5 which it does not it will not work
>   on windows.

– @Chris Hawkes

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've solved the problem now by reinstalling python 2.7. I was using python  2.7.8, and I switched into 2.7.11 which has pip installed automatically, and then I installed visual studio 2010.  And then I used pip to install twisted, and upgrade scrapy and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

(Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42673202/871373))
You can install Twisted on Python 3.5 by using the whl from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted). Then try installing Scrapy again.