# Twisted for python3.5？

Tags: python-3.x

There is no `Twisted` for python `3.5` at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted ,I am using python `3.5.2`,what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

I recently encounter a similar problem. 
try this Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

Use command "pip install yourfilename.whl"

I used it to fix the problem while installing scrapy

Answer (score 0):

Each new release of Twisted includes updates that bring full equal functionality to the python3 version. Releases are roughly monthly, so you may find that the module already works for you.

It is possible (for example with virtualenv) to install both python2 and 3 [How to install both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7)

Twisted support of python 3 on windows is lagging a little behind support on other systems. So if you have access to another OS you may find that it will allow you to install twisted for python 3.